# How to handle a mass if-statement

Tags: java, android, performance, if-statement

I need to make a if-elseif-statement with 768 different elements.

Is there any possibility to make it less effort to write? I know its a strange question, but I need to test 768 different messages.

So the question exactly is:

Is there a easy way for mass if-statements or do I just have to type all line for line?

If anything is not clear, feel free to ask.

**EDIT:**

```
private static final String TEST = "0 0 0 0 0 40 ";
private static final String TEST2 = "0 96 0 0 0 d6 ";
private static final String TEST3 = "1 28 0 0 1 68 ";
private static final String TEST4 = "2 07 0 0 2 47 ";
private static final String TEST5 = "2 be 0 0 2 fe ";

if (data.contains(TEST)){
        progress = 0;
} else if (data.contains(TEST2)) {
        progress = 20;
} else if (data.contains(TEST3)) {
        progress = 40;
} else if (data.contains(TEST4)) {
        progress = 70;
} else if (data.contains(TEST5)) {
        progress = 96;
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Here some Sample data for mathematical research:

```
00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00
00 01 00 00 00 41 00 00
00 02 00 00 00 42 00 00
00 03 00 00 00 43 00 00
00 04 00 00 00 44 00 00
00 05 00 00 00 45 00 00
00 06 00 00 00 46 00 00
00 07 00 00 00 47 00 00
00 08 00 00 00 48 00 00
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. 
01 00 00 00 01 40 00 00
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. 
02 00 00 00 02 40 00 00
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..
02 BF 00 00 02 FF 00 00
```

but sometimes on position 7 there is another hex number between 20 and 61. And thats the problem.

Comment: reflection could be of help... I don't think using swith cases makes it any easier...

Comment: Without *any clue* about what your conditions or actions will be, there's no way we can help you.

Comment: Well, we don't want to look at 768, but if you post a shorter snippet, we might be able to advise.

Comment: I would put those strings as resource with an index in the name, and the different progresses in an array, then you can use a for loop with an if inside to check data

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you check whether there isn't a simple(r) mathematical formula that describes the relation between the input value and the desired output value?

Comment: yeah, that was my first idea, to try to solve it as a mathematical problem. But no success until now

Comment: Post some sample "data" , is there a relation / serious between the Tests ?

Comment: If they're guaranteed to be hex numbers, then you could just use them as hex digits of one larger number.

Comment: From your sample code,assuming you don't care about 7th position. in that case the simple thought is keep the HashMap<String,Integer> for all 768 entries with 6 position and do substring upto 6th position in data then just do HashMap.get(substring) you will get the Number.

Comment: Pattern of your data on "second" position number start with 0 and end with BF ( 191) when it reach BF it adding 1 to first position and resets second position to 0 . Similarly 6th position starts with 40 and ends with FF ( difference between 40 and FF is 191 again) . when 6th position reach FF the fifth position adding 1 and resetting the 6th position to 40  . like wise you will get ( 191 *3 ) which is 573 numbers. it may give me some clue to come up remaining number by looking at sample of 7th position.  One Quick question . "in your sample code test2 return 20 " is right number on test2?

Comment: Its not reseting to 0. Position 2 goes from 00 to FF except if the first position is 2, then it only goes to BF. On position 6 it goes from 40 to FF, if position 5 is 00, and from 00 to FF, if position 5 is 01 or 02. So we got 256 + 256 + 191, so we got 703 messages. To your second question: Test2 returns 20, but there are also 6 other hexcodes that return 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to make a if-elseif-statement with 768 different elements.

No, you do not. You admit as much later in your question, when you wrote:

> I need to test 768 different messages

This does not require "a if-elseif-statement with 768 different elements". While that may be one way to solve the problem, as you note, it is not a great solution.

> Is there a easy way for mass if-statements or do I just have to type all line for line?

Do not do either of those.

Step #1: Get your test strings in an `HashMap<String, Integer>` (e.g., load them from an XML resource).

Step #2: Iterate over the `keySet()` of that `HashMap`, and test each key. If you have a match, set your `progress` equal to the corresponding value in the `HashMap`, and `break` out of the iteration loop.

Comment: Now as your answer seems the best until now, how do I load from an XML resource? Do I need an XML parser?

Comment: @Fraggles: Using an XML resource is merely one possibility. To go that route, create a `res/xml/` directory in your project, and store in there an XML representation of your key-value pairs. [Call `getXml()` on a `Resources` object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml%28int%29) (itself obtained via `getResources()` on a `Context`), passing in the appropriate `R.xml.*` ID of the resource. Use the `XmlPullParser` you get back to read in the XML.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `HashMap`.  Store the condition as the key, and the response as the value.

Comment: how will a hashmap help?

Comment: Well now that an actual code snippet is posted, a HashMap wouldn't be of much use.  If we just needed a `.equals()` then a Map<String, Integer> would work fine in this case.

Comment: @TheLostMind, you will always have to somehow input the values to check with. Map will help with checking process.

Comment: You mean a `LinkedHashMap`, so that the ordering can be controlled.

Comment: Yes if ordering is necessary.  It depends how much of an equivalent the OP needs to a chain of 768 if-else statements.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
static class TestWithProgress {
    final String test;
    final int progress;

    TestWithProgress(String test, int progress) {
        this.test = test;
        this.progress = progress;
    }
}

private static TestWithProgress[] TWIPS = new TestWithProgress[] {
    new TestWithProgress("0 0 0 0 0 40 ", 0),
    new TestWithProgress("0 96 0 0 0 d6 ", 20),
    ...
};
```

And now you may use a for loop:

```
for (TestWithProgress  twip : TWIPS) {
    if (data.contains(twip.test)) {
        progress = twip.progress;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If I have to face this issue, I may use

```
Switch(str){
case:strCheck
}
```

Comment: Switch statements on Strings requires Java 7. Android only supports up to Java 6